# Can I register to the GAC with Pascal scripting (InnoSetup)?

Tags: gac, inno-setup, pascal, global-assembly-cache, pascalscript

I'm using InnoSetup to install an application I built. My client requests that it downloads the latest DLLs upon install using this InnoSetup addon:

http://www.sherlocksoftware.org/page.php?id=50

Simple enough. I got it working how I want to, but without the **[Files]** section (because its downloading them rather than building them into the script), I'm not sure how to register the downloaded DLLs to the GAC. With the **[Files]** section in, I was using the flag *gacinstall*.

Now that I'm no longer using **[Files]**, I was wondering if there was a way to install the DLLs to the GAC via Pascal scripting?

Here is the relevant part of my setup script:

```
[Code]
procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
 itd_init;

 itd_addfile('{#DownloadLocation}/mylibrary1.dll',expandconstant('{tmp}\mylibrary1.dll'));
 itd_addfile('{#DownloadLocation}/mylibrary2.dll',expandconstant('{tmp}\mylibrary1.dll'));

 itd_downloadafter(wpReady);
end;

procedure CurStepChanged(CurStep: TSetupStep);
begin
 if CurStep=ssInstall then begin //Lets install those files that were downloaded for us     
  filecopy(expandconstant('{tmp}\mylibrary1.dll'),expandconstant('{app}\mylibrary1.dll'),false);
  filecopy(expandconstant('{tmp}\mylibrary2.dll'),expandconstant('{app}\mylibrary2.dll'),false);
 end;
end;


[Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Parameters: "-i"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, "&", "&&")}}"; Flags: runhidden  
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppSvcName}"; Parameters: "-i"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, "&", "&&")}}"; Flags: runhidden
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "Launch the ItraceIT configuration tool"; Flags: postinstall nowait skipifsilent

[UninstallRun]
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppSvcName}"; Parameters: "-u"; Flags: runhidden
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Parameters: "-u"; Flags: runhidden
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[Files]` Section, you can use the `external` flag to allow the files
that you have downloaded to run through the standard `[Files]` section, where the `gacinstall` flag is available.

```
[Files]
Source:{tmp}\mylibrary1.dll; DestDir:{app}; StrongAssemblyName: "MyAssemblyName, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=abcdef123456, ProcessorArchitecture=MSIL" Flags: external; gacinstall;
```

Then you don't need your call to `CurStepChanged` as the `[Files]` section will take care of that for you.

From the Pascal Scripting you could use the GAC API.

It's not officially documented, here are some articles that do a good job of covering it.

1. http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;317540
2. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/gacapi.aspx
3. http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/undocumentedfusion.aspx

You could build something yourself to Call the API or you could distribute [this application](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/GAC_Installer.aspx) and use it by calling `Exec`, or `ShellExec`.

Here is the [Delphi Code](http://cvs.jrsoftware.org/view/issrc/Projects/LibFusion.pas?revision=1.6&view=markup) ([CVS log](http://cvs.jrsoftware.org/view/issrc/Projects/LibFusion.pas?view=log)) to importing the fusion DLL that InnoSetup uses internally.

Comment: Updated as I realized you could use the `[Files]` section.

Answer (score 0):

If you can call into .NET code, you can register assemblies to the GAC using:

```
System.EnterpriseServices.Internal.Publish.GacInstall(string path)
```

which is available in the `System.EnterpriseServices` assembly.

Comment: InnoSetup produces Native code install.   So you can do this but must wrap this call into a interface that can be called out side of .NET